# How do I create groups with neighboring elements in a NxM matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, grouping, cluster-analysis

I need help grouping elements in a NxM matrix

Imagine a scenario where we have an NxM matrix representing a container, with indices indicating possible locations for stacking marbles. The goal is to group marbles based on their color and ensure they're in neighboring indices. It's important to note that the groups can have different numbers of marbles (i.e. 6 red marbles, 3 blue marbles, 9 gold).

To achieve this, I attempted to write Python code that accomplishes the following tasks:

1. Takes input from the user to create an NxM matrix.
2. Tries to divide the matrix into submatrices based on the number of groups and number of marbles in each group.
3. However, I encountered difficulties in allocating square submatrices of varying sizes within the matrix, and my code doesn't function properly.

I'm currently struggling to find the most suitable approach. It'd even be acceptable if the "submatrices" are treated as clusters rather than square matrices.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for
[Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpk3f.png)

Comment: Hi! For your example with 18 marbles (i.e. 6 red marbles, 3 blue marbles, 9 gold), would you mind explaining how your desired matrix would look like, using a specific example?

Comment: Hi Simon, I edited the post above to include a sample of what I'm looking for. Unfortunately not able to directly embed photos just yet.